# How do I ignore extra elements in an array when passing it as an argument into a method? (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, indices

What I was trying to do initially is, to find the corresponding index of an element in an given array and concatenate them. The code I have is

```rb
class ResistorColorDuo
  COLORS = %w{black brown red orange yellow green blue violet grey white}
    
  def self.value(colors_arry)
    colors_arry.map { |color| COLORS.index(color) }.join.to_i
  end

end

puts ResistorColorDuo.value(["brown", "orange"])
puts ResistorColorDuo.value(["black", "brown"])
puts ResistorColorDuo.value(["orange", "brown", "red"])
puts ResistorColorDuo.value(["orange", "brown", "red", "yellow"])

#13
#1
#312
#3124
```

It looks like there is no problem finding and concatenating them, but the real goal is to get the results only from the first two elements and ignore those coming after. For example, when passing `["orange", "brown", "red", "yellow"]` I should get `31` instead of `3124`. Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just include .first(2) also remove .to_i that will remove the 0 if it is in the beginning:

```
class ResistorColorDuo
  COLORS = %w{black brown red orange yellow green blue violet grey white}
    
  def self.value(colors_arry)
    colors_arry.first(2).map { |color| COLORS.index(color) }.join
  end

end

puts ResistorColorDuo.value(["brown", "orange"])
puts ResistorColorDuo.value(["black", "brown"])
puts ResistorColorDuo.value(["orange", "brown", "red"])
puts ResistorColorDuo.value(["orange", "brown", "red", "yellow"])
```

output will be:

```
13
01
31
31
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the output into Integer, then 0 index will disappear if it comes first.

```
class ResistorColorDuo
  COLORS = %w{black brown red orange yellow green blue violet grey white}
  def self.value(colors_arry)
    colors_arry.map { |color| COLORS.index(color) }.join.chars.shift(2).join
  end

end
p ResistorColorDuo.value(["brown", "orange"])
p ResistorColorDuo.value(["black", "brown"])
p ResistorColorDuo.value(["orange", "brown", "red"])
p ResistorColorDuo.value(["orange", "brown", "red", "yellow"])
```

Output

```
"13"
"01"
"31"
"31"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the first 2 elements from an array via [`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
ary = ["orange", "brown", "red"]

ary[0, 2] #=> ["orange", "brown"]
```

Where `0` is the starting index and `2` is the number of elements.

I've noticed that you are using a single class method to compute the resistor's value. Since Ruby is all about objects, it seems reasonable to work with *instances* and turn `value` into an instance method. This approach also allows to split the computation a bit, e.g.:

```
class Resistor
  COLORS = %i[black brown red orange yellow green blue violet grey white].freeze

  attr_accessor :color_bands

  def initialize(*color_bands)
    @color_bands = color_bands
  end

  def digits
    color_bands[0, 2].map { |color| COLORS.index(color) }
  end

  def value
    digits.join.to_i
  end
end

Resistor.new(:brown, :orange).value #=> 13
Resistor.new(:black, :brown).value  #=> 1
```

When working with 3 or 4 color bands, you could take the *multiplier* into account by adding it as a separate method:

```
class Resistor
   # ...

  def multiplier
    case color_bands.size
    when 1, 2 then 1
    when 3, 4 then 10 ** COLORS.index(color_bands[2])
    end
  end

  def value
    digits.join.to_i * multiplier
  end
end

Resistor.new(:orange, :brown, :red).value #=> 3100
```

In the above code, I've also changed the strings to symbols and used the splat operator `*` so you can simply pass a list of colors. (without having to wrap them in an array)